# Insert custom module inside node

Tags: 7

I have developed a custom module, containing a .module, a tepmlate-tpl.php , a .info, a .install a .css and a .js file, for a functionality I need for my Drupal-7 site.
Although I know how and have already placed it at a new page(via .module file), I want to place the exact functionality/display at an existing node, where the node--xx.tpl.php already has it's own content.
I want to render the whole module inside the node's tpl or using another method.
Is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Quite a vague description, but turn it into a field?

Comment: I am sorry if the description is vague, but the testing is made at a local site. My question, to sum up, is how can I add a custom module, one with coupons for a e-shop, at the end of an already existing page. This page is made with an article and formatting its node.tpl.php, but the functionality I wanted was too complicated so I decided to make a module, which currently is at a different page. I want the module to show at the end of the article. As for the field, do you mean the user's field? I think that it isn't suitable for my purpose